# How to set is_in_stock to 0 for configurable product when all associated products are out of stock?

Tags: magento-1

I am using a third party service to generate and submit the product feed to Google.This service uses **is_in_stock** field from the **cataloginventory_stock_item** database table to check if the product is in stock or not?

I have check in the default Magento even if we make all the associated products of a configurable product out of stock the **is_in_stock** value is set to **1** only.

Or do we have any other attribute in any of Magento table which may help?
Is there any way to work around this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do this using `magento event and observe and on create an event on catalog_product_save_after` and check on obsever child product are out stock an set configurable accoring to ite

```
<global>
            <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <stockalert>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>check/observer</class>
                        <method>autoupdatemy</method>
                    </stockalert>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
</global>
```

and observer.php

```
 public function autoupdatemy($observer)
{
    try{
        $isstcok=false;
        if($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getData('type_id')=='configurable'){
        $ConfiProduct=$observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $allProducts = $ConfiProduct->getTypeInstance(true)
        ->getUsedProducts(null, $ConfiProduct);

            foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
                /* check one child product is out of stock */
            if($product->getIsInStock()==1):
            $isstcok=true;
            endif;
            }

        /* load configuale product  stock object */ 
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($ConfiProduct);
        if($isstcok=true):
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
        else:
            $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 0);
        endif;
        $stockItem->save();
        }
    }catch(Excpetion $e){
    Mage::log(print_r($e->getMessage(),1),'null','mage32173.log');
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: muk,is it working??